# Break text defined length blocks from a long text using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm need to break a long text field into one or more repetitions containing part of this long text with defined length (ie. 50 ch) using xsl.
INPUT EXAMPLE:

....
**<longText>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

</longText>**

....

I'm expecting the following output:
....
**<pieceOfLongTextElement>

 <step>1</step>

 <text>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a</text>

</pieceOfLongTextElement>

<pieceOfLongTextElement>

 <step>2</step>

 <text>nd typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </text>

</pieceOfLongTextElement>**


and so until the long text length is reached increasing step from 50 to 50 chars...

Thanks.

Comment: Which XSLT processor respectively XSLT version do you use or can you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2.0 you can simply break up the string using `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="longText">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=".{{1,50}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <piece step="{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </piece>                
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LWa/1 which outputs

```
<piece step="1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a</piece>
<piece step="2">nd typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the </piece>
<piece step="3">industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</piece>
<piece step="4">s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type a</piece>
<piece step="5">nd scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</piece>
```